# Why the version tab is missing for some .exe files?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008, version

My software project includes a set of .exe files, developed and compiled using visual C++ 6.0 SP6 and Visual Studio 2008 (C#). My builder (Finalbuilder) updates the version info of the projects automatically and then compiles them. I wonder why some of my .exe files are missing the version tab in the file properties dialog (right click on file -> properties). This tab is essential for deployment, because my colleagues should check the version before deploying them. I am using Windows XP SP3 for development and deployment.

Comment: What are the exes with the missing info? The C++ or the C# ones?

Comment: The simple explanation is that the file version resource is not in fact present.  Easy to check in VS2008, use File + Open + File and select the .exe.  You'll see the unmanaged resources, "Version" should be present.

Comment: @rodrigo: This happens for both C++ and C# apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version info is a resource and no .exe attribute i think. So check if you really attached that resource.

Comment: So it is. If the Ressource is missing you will see no Version tab

Comment: thanks. But the version info resource is already present in all projects.

Comment: Finally found the point. The builder was changing the version info in a wrong way.